# Style Layout independent of Activity's Theme

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-styles

I'm using a Custom Default Theme which is specified in the Applications Manifest within the `<activity>` tag:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

However for one child layout in this activity I would like to apply a different theme.

Therefore I'm applying a theme directly to the child layout:

```
<LinearLayout>
   ...
   <LinearLayout
    ...
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeLight">
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This works fine in Android Version 21+ however not in older versions.

Is there any possibility or workaround to do this in Android 20 or older?
The child layout is rather complex and I would like to avoid applying 
`style="@style/AppThemeLight"` to each and every child of this layout.

By the way I'm simply trying to change the textColor in this child layout.

Answer (score 0):

try doing this

```
<LinearLayout
 ...
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 ...>
  ...
  <LinearLayout
    ...
    app:theme="@style/AppThemeLight">
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and then

Comment: if you refer to setting the default theme within <application> instead of <activity> tag of the manifest: that doesn't work either.

Comment: i've clarified my awnser

Comment: oh. maybe you wrote the style inside the styles.xml in the res/values-21 folder. Make sure you set the styles on res/values/